# Convert dynamic string into logical expressions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

This one might be a little difficult as I haven't seen anyone attempt this besides standard operators.

I have a table with about 50k rows of objects, each row needs to run a set of expressions "up to 30" against them and return true or false. I've successfully done this with mass tenary operators but it gets messy really quick.

Someone have a better approach? Minimal Code Below - problem lies within the validate function.

```
const objects = [
    {
        'First Name': 'Chris',
        'Age': 18,
        'Major': 'Mathematics',
        'College Department': 'Mathematics'
    },
    {
        'First Name': 'null',
        'Age': 21,
        'Major': 'Mathematics',
        'College Department': 'Science'
    }
]

const validate = (object, rule) => {
    // logic to convert rule to logical expression
}

const results = objects.map(object => {
    var flags = []
    flags.push(validate(object, '[Fist Name] is null'))
    flags.push(validate(object, '[Age] < [Required Age]'))
    flags.push(validate(object, '[Major] === [College Department] and [Age] > [Required Age]'))  
    // Validate is supposed to return 
    // {Rule: '[Fist Name] is null', Flag: false/true, ...Rest of original object and key pairs} 

    // ... Return array of flags
    return flags;
})

// Result should look like this
// lets say required age is 18
[
    [
        {Rule: '[Fist Name] is null', Flag: false, 'First Name': 'Chris', 'Age': 18, 'Major': 'Mathematics', 'College Department': 'Mathematics'},
        {Rule: '[Age] < [Required Age]', Flag: false, 'First Name': 'Chris', 'Age': 18, 'Major': 'Mathematics', 'College Department': 'Mathematics'},
        {Rule: '[Major] === [College Department] and [Age] > [Required Age]', Flag: true, 'First Name': 'Chris', 'Age': 18, 'Major': 'Mathematics', 'College Department': 'Mathematics'}   
    ],
    [
        {Rule: '[Fist Name] is null', Flag: true, 'First Name': 'null', 'Age': 21, 'Major': 'Mathematics', 'College Department': 'Science'},
        {Rule: '[Age] < [Required Age]', Flag: false, 'First Name': 'null', 'Age': 21, 'Major': 'Mathematics', 'College Department': 'Science'},
        {Rule: '[Major] === [College Department] and [Age] > [Required Age]', Flag: false, 'First Name': 'null', 'Age': 21, 'Major': 'Mathematics', 'College Department': 'Science'}  
    ]
]

// I know how to concat the arrays into one, 
// so either the above output works or the one below works
[
    {Rule: '[Fist Name] is null', Flag: false, 'First Name': 'Chris', 'Age': 18, 'Major': 'Mathematics', 'College Department': 'Mathematics'},
    {Rule: '[Age] < [Required Age]', Flag: false, 'First Name': 'Chris', 'Age': 18, 'Major': 'Mathematics', 'College Department': 'Mathematics'},
    {Rule: '[Major] === [College Department] and [Age] > [Required Age]', Flag: true, 'First Name': 'Chris', 'Age': 18, 'Major': 'Mathematics', 'College Department': 'Mathematics'}, 
    {Rule: '[Fist Name] is null', Flag: true, 'First Name': 'null', 'Age': 21, 'Major': 'Mathematics', 'College Department': 'Science'},
    {Rule: '[Age] < [Required Age]', Flag: false, 'First Name': 'null', 'Age': 21, 'Major': 'Mathematics', 'College Department': 'Science'},
    {Rule: '[Major] === [College Department] and [Age] > [Required Age]', Flag: false, 'First Name': 'null', 'Age': 21, 'Major': 'Mathematics', 'College Department': 'Science'}  
]
```

**Update** This is how far i've come but can only do this for >, <=, > or atleast thats all i've tested thus far. I will add more comments detailing soon.

```
const object = {Age: 10, Required: 18};
const rules = [
    {R: '["Age"] < ["Required"]', O: ['<']},
    {R: '["Age"] <= ["Required"]', O: ['<=']},
    {R: '["Age"] > ["Required"]', O: ['>']},
]

// Prototype that will parse the string
// ... then return the indexes of char
// ... we will use this to insert object name before the char
String.prototype.toIndices = function (d) { return this.split("").reduce((a, e, i) => e === d ? a.concat(i) : a, []) };

String.prototype.splice = function(idx, rem, str) {
    return this.slice(0, idx) + str + this.slice(idx + Math.abs(rem));
};

Object.prototype.validateRule = function (r) {
    const newString = r['R'].toIndices("[").map(s => {
        return r['R'].splice(s, 0, 'object');
    })

    var exp = [];

    for (let item = 0; item < newString.length; item++) {
        for (let obj = 0; obj < newString[item].split(" ").length; obj++) {
            if (newString[item].split(" ")[obj].includes("object"))
                exp.push(newString[item].split(" ")[obj])
        }
    }

    return [...exp].map((e, i) => i < exp.length - 1 ? [e, r['O'][0]] : [e]).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b)).join(" ");
}


console.log({Rule: rules[0]['R'], Flag: eval(object.validateRule(rules[0]))});
// output
/*
{ Rule: '["Age"] < ["Required"]', Flag: true }
*/

console.log(rules.map(rule => { return {Rule: rule['R'], Flag: eval(object.validateRule(rule))} }));
// output
/*
[ { Rule: '["Age"] < ["Required"]', Flag: true },
  { Rule: '["Age"] <= ["Required"]', Flag: true },
  { Rule: '["Age"] > ["Required"]', Flag: false } ]
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of creating and revising I've developed a solution to convert string into logical expression. I made a package out of it at:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/validate-table-rules

**Installation**

```
npm install validate-table-rules
```

Quickstart

```
'use strict';

//  Required module
const ruleSet = require('validate-table-rules');

// Attach module to Object prototype
Object.prototype.rule = ruleSet.rules;

// Declare and object
const object = [
    {Age: 18, Required: 21}
];

// Sample case -> pass in names you
// want to check for in attached object
console.log(object.rule('[Age] < [Required]')) // output = true
console.log(object.rule('[Age] > [Required]')) // output = false
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

If the expressions you need to evaluate are known ahead of time, write the expressions out in code.

```
const rules = new Map()
rules.set("[First Name] is null", function(object) {
    return object.firstName === null
})
```

It's a lot of work to create your own mini language. If you need to let users add custom rules, then it makes sense to build a rule parser and evaluation engine.

---

In parsing code, the way to evaluate the expression is usually to break the input into tokens, and then evaluate the tokens in a second step.

```
function parse(textInput) {
    return arrayOfTokens
}
```

Example Text Input: `[Fist Name] is null`

Example Array of Tokens: `[ new Field("First Name"), new OpIsNull() ]`

Write lots of unit tests for different text inputs and make sure it returns the expected tokens. When the parsing is working correctly, the next step is to evaluate the tokens. Write lots of unit tests for arrays of tokens, objects, and the expected output value.

```
function evaluate(object, tokens) {
    let leftHand = null
    if (tokens[0] instanceof Field) {
        leftHand = getFieldValue(object, tokens[0])
    }
    if (tokens[1] instanceof OpIsNull) {
        return leftHand === null
    }
    // etc
}

function getFieldValue(object, field) {
    if (field.name == "First Name") {
        return object.firstName
    }
}
```

Comment: I am willing to make a dedicated parser as this will be used going forward in our environment years to come, just needed a direction to go into. I will look into this and yes I have known rules right now but the will most likely be new ones added so having a way to just enter a rule and it parse the object based off it will save a lot of work for others that might take over this task of managing